# Clear ListView (firemonkey)

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder

I'm building an FMX app for Windows that has a button and a TListView control.  The button code is just a query of an SQLite db used to populate the TListView.  Under some circumstances the query takes 5-10 seconds to process.  I'd like to immediately clear the TListView when the button is clicked (before the query gets done and repopulates the list).  At the first of the button code i have a call to the Clear method but it doesn't work immediately:

```
ListView1->Clear();
```

The old data remains in the TListView control until after the query completes and refreshes it.  How can i force the list to empty FIRST.

thanks,
russ

UPDATED to clearly show what is happening:

```
// This entire block of code below is inside a button click.
Form1->ListView1->Clear();
// This next line of code is what Frederico suggested - it works.
Application->ProcessMessages();

Form1->FDConnection1->Params->Values["Database"] = "T:\\mydata.db";
TFDQuery *query;
query = new TFDQuery(NULL);
query->Connection = Form1->FDConnection1;    // SQLite db
query->SQL->Text = "SELECT DISTINCT Project FROM Engineer_Updates WHERE Employee = '" + Form1->lblEngineerInitials->Text + "' ORDER BY Project";
query->Open();
  while(!query->Eof) {
    TListViewItem* itemHeader = Form1->ListView1->Items->Add();
    Form1->ListView1->BeginUpdate();
    itemHeader->Purpose = TListItemPurpose::Header;
    itemHeader->Text = query->FieldByName("Project")->AsString; // + " - " + query->FieldByName("Project WO")->AsString;  // "My Header";
    Form1->ListView1->EndUpdate();
        TFDQuery *query2;
        query2 = new TFDQuery(NULL);
            try {
            query2->Connection = Form1->FDConnection2;    // SQLite db
            query2->SQL->Text = "SELECT * FROM Engineer_Updates WHERE Project = '" + query->FieldByName("Project")->AsString + "' AND Employee = '" + Form1->lblEngineerInitials->Text + "'";
            query2->Open();
                 while (!query2->Eof) {
                  TListViewItem* item2Add = Form1->ListView1->Items->Add();
                  Form1->ListView1->BeginUpdate();
                  item2Add->Text = query2->FieldByName("Terminal/Equipment")->AsString + ", " + query2->FieldByName("Activity")->AsString;
                  mystring2 = query2->FieldByName("Terminal/Equipment")->AsString + ", " + query2->FieldByName("Activity")->AsString;
                  item2Add->Detail = mystring2;
                  Form1->ListView1->EndUpdate();
                  query2->Next();
                }
            }
            __finally {
              query2->Close();
              query2->DisposeOf();
            }
    query->Next();
    }
    query->Close();
    query->DisposeOf();
```

Comment: You need to provide more information in your question. Now there are two different answers and both a just guessing on information that is not provided.

Comment: Have you tried calling Application.ProcessMessages after ListView1.clear?

Comment: Hi Federico - that solved the problem.  I simply added  Application->ProcessMessages();  after the clear statement.  Thank you!  - russ

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution (using Delphi code):

```
ListView1.Clear;
//eventually show a spinning wheel here, so the user knows something is going on.
ListView1.InvalidateRect(ListView1.BoundsRect); //<- might not be needed, try first without
TThread.ForceQueue(nil, procedure
  begin
    //execute your query here and fill the listview
    //stop the spinning wheel
  end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is TListView binded via BindSource ? If yes please try clear data using separated Thread e.g anonymous thread and disable dataset in bindsource

```
BindSourceDB1.DataSet.Active := False;
TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(procedure ()
begin
    // delete data here using separated query
    TThread.Synchronize(nil, procedue ()
    begin
        BindSourceDB1.DataSet.Active := True;
    end);
end).Start;
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on edit and add a paragraph or two summarizing how your code addresses the question, or perhaps  explain how your answer differs from the previous answer/answers. Thanks.